# Memory model release/acquire mode interactions of relaxed atomic operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, memory-model, stdatomic

The GCC Wiki says this about the memory model synchronization mode [Acquire/Release](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync#Acquire.2BAC8-Release):

> To make matters a bit more complex, the interactions of non-atomic variables are still the same. Any store before an atomic operation must be seen in other threads that synchronize. For example:
>
> ```
>  -Thread 1-
>  y = 20;
>  x.store (10, memory_order_release);
>
>  -Thread 2-
>  if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10)
>     assert (y == 20);
> ```
>
> Since 'y' is not an atomic variable, the store to 'y' *happens-before* the store to 'x', so the assert cannot fail in this case. The optimizers must still limit the operations performed on shared memory variables around atomic operations.

Now, what if I make 'y' an atomic variable (without imposing *happens-before* restrictions)?

```
 -Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_relaxed);
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10)
    assert (y.load (memory_order_relaxed) == 20);
```

Can the assert fail? Are there fewer requirements for atomic variables than for non-atomic variables? Or is the Wiki's restriction to non-atomic variables gratuitous and misleading here?

Comment: Anything guaranteed for regular memory operations is also guaranteed for relaxed atomic operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since 'y' is not an atomic variable, the store to 'y' happens-before the store to 'x'

The statement "since `y` is not an atomic" is incorrect.. 
The same ordering rules apply to atomic and non-atomic operations.

Acquire/release barriers guarantee that memory operation A (the store to `y`) sequenced before the store/release *happens-before* memory operation B (the `assert`)
sequenced after the load/acquire that sees the stored value. Whether or not operations A and B are atomic is irrelevant.
The `assert` cannot fire.